# How do I avoid Outlook attachments being checked out when saving to SharePoint?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, outlook

I currently have VBA in Outlook to check new messages for attachments with certain names. If found, it saves them to my I: drive, which is mapped to a SharePoint folder. It deletes the current version, and replaces it with the new one.

It all works fine, except that when the attachments are saved, they are checked out to me. This causes issues, as other users cannot see them until I go in and manually check in.

Can I add some code to avoid a checkout, or automatically check in/abandon check out? I know how to do it if I have the code open the file, check it in, and close it. But as I am often actively working in PowerQuery when the code executes, this isn't really ideal.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder, SharePointDrive As String
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim UserDrives As Variant
    'Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    For Each UserDrives In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").drives
        If UserDrives.DriveType = 3 And InStr(UCase(UserDrives.sharename), "SHAREPOINT") > 0 Then SharePointDrive = UserDrives.driveletter
    Next
    If Len(SharePointDrive) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    sSaveFolder = SharePointDrive & ":\Reference Files\"
    Set olFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    For Each Item In olFolder.Items
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            For Each oAttachment In Item.Attachments
                If oAttachment.DisplayName Like "*Pricing*" Then
                    Kill sSaveFolder & "PricingData.xlsx"
                    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "PricingData.xlsx"
                    Item.Delete
                ElseIf oAttachment.DisplayName Like "*Mileage*" Then
                    Kill sSaveFolder & "Mileage.xlsx"
                    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & "Mileage.xlsx"
                    Item.Delete
                End If
            Next oAttachment
        End If
    Next Item
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for checking in or out files in SharePoint.

As a possible workaround you may consider saving attached files into any local folder and then moving them programmatically to the mapped folder by replacing old files there.

Comment: Do you think sourcing it from a local drive and copying it would avoid checking it out? I feel like the net result is the same: you are creating a new file on the SharePoint path.

Comment: Just a wild thought. But, anyway, that is more SharePoint question rather than Outlook.

Comment: I don't know if it would make a difference to your comment, but I have turned on the Excel 16.0 Object library in the Outlook VBA Editor. So I do have access to the commands like .CheckIn, but the problem is that this specific one only works on open workbooks...

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct. I was able to find a setting in SharePoint that required checking out to edit. It stated that this also meant new files were checked out, as well as other users not seeing your edits until checked in.

When turned off, the new file now is not checked out.

I appreciate your assistance!